# Postgres | how to combine from two or more table into single table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

i have lots of data which is divided into two or more tables.Then how to fetch the data from all the table.

First table is point table which is divided into three parts

```
first table = ab_p1_point
second table = ab_p2_point
third table = ab_p3_point
```

---

Another table is line table which is again divided into three parts

```
first table = bc_p1_line
second table = bc_p2_line
third table = bc_p3_line
```

How to combine all the parts of point tables into single point table and all the parts of line tables into single line table than perform operation between both the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all three tables have the same structure, you could potentially use `union all`:

```
select * from (
    select f1, f2, f3 from ab_p1_point
    union all
    select f1, f2, f3 from ab_p2_point
    union all
    select f1, f2, f3 from ab_p3_point
) t
where f1 = 'abc'
```

You could make it simpler to work with by putting the query into a view.

But why are you breaking up your rows across multiple tables?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE (`WITH` statement):

```
WITH points AS (
    SELECT * FROM ab_p1_point
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM ab_p2_point
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM ab_p3_point
    )
,  lines AS (
    SELECT * FROM bc_p1_line
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM bc_p2_line
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM bc_p3_line
    )
SELECT * 
FROM points
INNER JOIN lines 
ON points.column = lines.column
```